# Book where a boy replies to a job ad for a wizard's apprentice and passes through a portal at the interview

Tags: story-identification, magic, wizards

I read a series of books a few years back.

It was about a boy who, upon finishing school, decides to apply to an ad about a job. The ad states: Wizard's apprentice, no illusions. Real magic.

When he arrives for an interview, he reads a book about magic in the waiting room. He then walks through the door to the interview room, and this door is the portal to another world.

He starts to learn about magic from the book as he explores. He is soon attacked by wolves and saved by an archer.  This archer takes him to a village that becomes his home.

In aiding the town he rids an old house (I believe) of some magical/ghostly shirt.

He gains skill fast, gains a home and enlists a younger boy who, due to a magical amulet, ages fast and becomes a skilled warrior.

In the end, he establishes a religion that the younger boy becomes the leader of at the end.

Comment: Removed the "portal" tag as that seems to refer to the video game Portal

Answer (score 7):

I once read the first book of a series that started like this.  It was called *[The Unsuspecting Mage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001A40H0I)* which is the first book in the "The Morcyth Saga" by Brian S. Pratt.

> “Want to be a mage? Then do we have the job for you…”
>
> Sounds great for a veteran role-player. When on-the-job training entails battling demons, learning magic through trial and error, and living in a world without toilet paper, things could get rough. But to be dropped in the middle of a forest and having to do it on your own with no instruction…welcome to James’ world.
>
> It all gets started when his grandfather suggests to James, a young man on the verge of graduating high school, that he check out the following advertisement for a job.
>
> “Magic! Real Magic! Ever wanted to learn? We require someone with intelligence and a disciplined mind. Those well versed in fantasy novels and role playing games a plus. May need to travel.”

Comment: Honestly, a book I found mildly mediocre in the "isekai protagonist is destined to success, bugger the plot" manner.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Shadowland by Peter Straub?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowland_(Straub_novel)